# Memory size of 1073741824 exhausted - Twig Environment Symfony2

Tags: symfony, caching, twig

For some reason, I am suddenly getting the following Fatal error when clearing my cache in my Symfony2 project:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instorecrm/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php on line 286
```

When I refer to the line 286 in the Environment.php file, it is this function:

```
public function getCacheFilename($name)
    {
        @trigger_error(sprintf('The %s method is deprecated and will be removed in Twig 2.0.', __METHOD__), E_USER_DEPRECATED);

        $key = $this->cache->generateKey($name, $this->getTemplateClass($name));

        return !$key ? false : $key;
    }
```

I cannot think of anthing I've done that would cause this, the only change I have made is to the parameters.yml file to stipulate Gmail as my mail host. It does not seem to affect the working of the site (at least I have not found it to as yet) but it worries me that something might be broken.

I am using localhost, if that helps any.

Any help appreciated,

Thank you
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the cache manually by deleting the `app/cache` folder.

Comment: Unfortunately, even after deleting that directory the issue still occurs when running the cache clear script. For some reason, it creates 4 folders in the cache, dev, prod, de_ and pro_ - shouldn't this only be dev and prod?

Comment: It's far too big to publish here, but basically it starts with this: `php.INFO: The Twig_Function class is deprecated since version 1.12 and will be removed in 2.0. Use Twig_SimpleFunction instead.` Also, there are multiple mentions of the oneup_uploader module having deprecated functions such as oneup_uploader_maxsize. Could this potentially be causing the issue?

Comment: No, just the trace,  not the log,  it s only few lines

Comment: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 130968 bytes) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/instorecrm/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Environment.php on line 378`

Comment: This is the error line,  I need the trace,  it s a kind of log which shows the propagation of the error in Silex. It s generally 10 lines.

Comment: OK sorry to sound dumb but what is Silex? The only logs I have are prod.log and dev.log situated within the app/logs folder. Are you referring to a bundle which I need to install? Or can I access these somewhere else?

Comment: Sorry, I mean Symfony

Comment: Like in this example : http://symfony.com/uploads/assets/fatal_error_after.png The trace is the 9 lines bellow.

Comment: Ah I see - there is no error on the site, it works fine, it even clears the cache in the end, but I just get that error line pop up in the terminal after each cache clearing / warmup. Here is a screenshot of the console after running the command: http://postimg.org/image/4bzfcdelb/

Comment: Unfortunately same error. I'm not sure why it's referencing Twig to be honest - I cannot recall what I did that may cause this.

Comment: Have you added this to your php `cli` line?

Comment: I changed it in php.ini but in my experience all this does is just drain more memory because I'm guessing there is a memory leak somewhere along the line

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, for me it solved the problem.